# puppet catalog run error Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /<path/to/my/file>

Tags: ubuntu, puppet

I recently updated my `ubuntu 12.04` VM instances (in OpenStack) to `ubuntu 14.04` of which puppet master and puppet agent separately installed.
While doing the OS upgrade my puppet master and agent both upgraded from `2.7.11` to `3.4.3`.

I ran a sample test puppet catalog run by simply creating a file in agent's /tmp directory and it was successful.

But when I tried to move files from my master to agent node I'm getting the following error [which was working fine before puppet upgrade].
I have several modules inside /etc/puppet/modules/ which was working fine with puppet 2.7.11

```
    root@appserver-mgr:~# puppet agent --test
    Info: Retrieving plugin
    Info: Loading facts in /var/lib/puppet/lib/facter/java_home.rb
    Info: Caching catalog for appserver-mgr.openstacklocal
    Info: Applying configuration version '1416908414'
    Notice:                 /Stage[main]/Appserver::Config_mgr/Exec[Stop_process_and_remove_CARBON_HOME]/returns: executed successfully
    Notice: /Stage[main]/Appserver::Config_mgr/Exec[remove_java_dirs]/returns: executed successfully
    Error: /Stage[main]/Appserver::Config_mgr/File[/opt/wso2as-5.2.1.zip]: Could not evaluate: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/appserver/wso2as-5.2.1.zip with {:links=>"manage"} Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///appserver/wso2as-5.2.1.zip: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/appserver/wso2as-5.2.1.zip with {:links=>"manage"}
    Error: /Stage[main]/Appserver::Config_mgr/File[/opt/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz]: Could not evaluate: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/packs/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz with {:links=>"manage"} Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///packs/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz: Error 400 on SERVER: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/packs/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz with {:links=>"manage"}`
```

puppet class file contents:

```
    file { '/opt/wso2as-5.2.1.zip':
            replace => "no",
            ensure => present,
            source => "puppet:///appserver/wso2as-5.2.1.zip",
    }

    file { '/opt/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz':
            replace => "no",
            ensure => present,
            source => "puppet:///packs/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz",
    }
```

My files locations have also not been changed.

Glad if anyone can provide a direction to proceed from here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer.

```
    file { '/opt/wso2as-5.2.1.zip':
            replace => "no",
            ensure => present,
            source => "puppet:///modules/appserver/wso2as-5.2.1.zip",
    }

    file { '/opt/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz':
            replace => "no",
            ensure => present,
            source => "puppet:///modules/packs/jdk1.6.0_24.tar.gz",
    }
```

After puppet upgrade, I had to rename file path by adding a /modules/ section after ///

Earlier versions worked without modules/ part, albeit it was deprecated since Puppet v 0.25. See the details here: http://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/3/reference/release_notes.html#break-puppet-urls-pointing-to-module-files-must-contain-modules

Then the puppet catalog run was successful for the new version.

Comment: I am getting this error : `Error: /Stage[main]/Mymodule/File[/home/nidhi/mybash.sh]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet:///mymodule/files/mybash.sh: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: Not authorized to call find on /file_metadata/mymodule/files/mybash.sh with {:rest=>"mymodule/files/mybash.sh", :links=>"manage", :checksum_type=>"md5", :source_permissions=>"ignore"}`, can someone help me in resolving this?